# Rails 4: Append to a "has_many" relation without saving to DB

Tags: ruby, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

In Rails 3 one can do things like `some_post.comments.append(some_comment)` where some posts is an instance of a model that "has_many" comments.

The problem I'm facing in Rails 4 is that the `append` method now saves to DB (like `push` and `<<` ) and I need to just "append" without saving the appended object to the DB.

How do we achieve that in Rails 4? I can't use `some_post.comments.build(some_comment.attributes)` because I need to preserve the other relations already present in the `some_comment` instance.

Comment: You mean, you need to append a comment and then perform some operation on the parent object, so you're trying to avoid persisting the new comment right away?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

It's oddly difficult to do this elegantly in Rails. This is the cleanest way I've found:

```
post.association(:comments).add_to_target(comment)
```

Comment: 2nd way: post.comments.proxy_association.add_to_target(comment)

Answer (score 2):

You can do it without using reflection on the association:

```rb
post.comments.build(
  attr_1: value_1,
  attr_1: value_2,
  # Other comment attributes
)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many: comments, autosave: false

  ...
end
```

Then << will just append and not save.

Comment: Doing this also removes auto-saving of the association when the parent is saved.